# Binary data stream to text file conversion in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

```
clc 
clear all 
close all
[f_name,path] = uigetfile({'*.txt';'*.*'},'Select the Text (.txt) file'); 

path=[path f_name]; %building the path of the text file
A = importdata(path); %import a text data as a structure
x=A(1);
for i=2:size(A,1)
x=strcat(x,'\n'); %preserving a line brake like this, it will be helpful 
while reconstruction
x=strcat(x, A(i));
end %this loop is to concatenate all the characters in a continuous sequence 

x=x{1}; %converting structure to a character array 
c=dec2bin(x,8); %create a cell of x character & 8bit 
y=c(1,:); %for a continoues bit stream
for i=2:size(c,1)
y=strcat(y,c(i,:));
end
for i=1:size(y,2)
z(i)=double(y(i));
end
z(find(z(:)==48))=0;
z(find(z(:)==49))=1;%z is a bitstream now
disp('The Resultant Bit Stream is:');
disp(z);
```

I have this code to convert text file to binary conversion and store in array.Now, I have to convert this bit stream data to text and save this file again.Can anyone suggest the MATLAB code for this reverse conversion??

Comment: `char(bin2dec(z))` to convert back to decimal (ASCII) and then a character array?

Comment: @Suever It is showing that input must be string, and z is a row matrix?